# Knot theory and creative writing?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I am a Ph.D. Candidate in Creative Writing and an M.S. Student in Mathematics and I'm writing my master's thesis on knot theory and trying to tie in applications to creative writing. Has anyone come across any sources that explicitly use knot theory as a basis/structure/theoretical underpinning for creative writing/composition? The Oulipo often use combinatorics but I am looking primarily for knot theory focused writing/theory. Thanks!

Comment: You might also benefit from writing.se (I've known them to cover questions with academic bent).

Comment: I have no idea what creative writing is about, but maybe one can do something about modeling different approaches to time travel with braids. Or one might try to order social relations (like debts, favors etc) in a cyclic way leading to some easy knots...

Comment: The Oulipo, as far as I know, use combinatorics in a "non-narrative" way: to motivate [*stylistic constraints*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulipo#Constraints) which their texts must follow. E.g. "don't use the letter 'E'" has no impact on the *content* of the story itself, just on how it's written. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for, or do you want knot theory to be used in the content of the stories, or something in between?

Comment: This is a lecture I attended titled "Knots to Narnia."   It might give you some ideas.  You will even spot me in the background of this video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g43FqgUpyNo

Comment: Is knot theory not creative writing of its own? If so any good paper or book on knot theory would work. :)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am not interested in content of stories. I'm looking for a way that knot theory might be used as a structure for creation of stories. Like how the Oulipo uses combinatorics to structure their stories.

Comment: Is writing intricate narratives your objective :) ?

Comment: Cross-posted to [MO here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/382660/6094).

Comment: Here's an idea: if you think of one of the three spatial dimensions as being time, then a knot corresponds to arrangements of points moving in 2D with three kinds of events: (1) a pair of points are born from nothing, moving away from each other, (2) a pair of points collide and disappear, and (3) points dance around each other.  All of this behavior from another point of view is a single particle weaving forward and backward in time.  You could use a knot to generate a framework for a narrative.  (You might look up the tangle category https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/tangles.html)

Comment: http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf569